# Do you need to restrict the possible characters of a username?

Tags: authentication

I was looking at Twitter login system and saw this error message when trying to enter a username

> Your username can only contain letters, numbers and '_'.

Twitter offer the possibility to login either by email, phone or username. So when you fill out the login form you can either input {email, password} or {username, password} for example.

I'm guessing that this error message is there to stop a user from choosing an email address as a username.

**Would it be a problem if the username was an email address too?**

**Tip** : What happens when someone use an address email they do not own as their username and then the legitimate user of this email try to create an account...

**EDIT** : I believe that this goes much further than simply user experience and can be abuse as an anti-competitive practice by malicious companies. See my answer below for details.

**EDIT2** : Here is an example. You create an account with the following setting :

- username : billgates@microsoft.com
- email : my-email@gmail.com
- password : strongpassword

You then receive a confirmation message only for my-email@gmail.com, which you own, and you have effectively block Bill Gates from using his address billgates@microsoft.com to create an account on the website.

Repeat that process 1000s of time and you will block plenty of users from using their favorite address. Users which might decide to don't use your service because of a poor experience and the company would lose a lot of money.

Comment: Is there any basis to "guessing that this error message is there to stop a user from choosing an email address as a username"?

Comment: @Matthew It's frequent enough that user will receive email about account they did not created that twitter created an help page for this. https://support.twitter.com/articles/110202?lang=en# Now I'm wondering if we could set an email as a username how they would handle this. Currently, they are sending confirmation email when you chose your email but not when your chose a username.

Comment: That would appear to be a user experience decision - they want people to be able to sign up and start using the service without waiting for verification, possibly as a result of mobile accounts (which they started off with). It would be entirely possible to verify email addresses without any changes to the usernames. However, if they did use email addresses as usernames, think about the number of email addresses that would be published on Twitter pages...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a user experience question and not a security question.

Comment: @NeilSmithline You seem to underestimate the consequence of the problem. If you allow an address email as a username you could deny service to a company for a ton of users. For example, 2 companies provide a similar service. Company A doesn't want its users to switch to Company B. So, Company A, for every user they have, will create an account on company B using the email of their client as a username, Then when a user of A try to create an account for B, he will receive a message telling him that there is already an account even if he didn't created one.

Comment: @ꓨꓵꓷꓤꓯꓷꓯꓲꓠ I strongly believe that twitter and service with a similar login process can tell the difference and would either not accept such a username or treat it as email-address (always) so that your described scenario does not hold. Specifically when you register you have different fields for username and email, so there really can't be a confusion.

Answer (score 2):

There is slightly more reason to restrict the characters of a username than to restrict the characters of a password. Essentially, the username acts as a record identifier in a login system - you need to make use of the input to find the password hash in your login system. With prepared database statements, this isn't really an issue, but lots of systems don't use prepared statements - hence the sheer number of SQL injection attacks that are still possible.

If you're not using prepared statements, you have two options. First, you can pass through the unmodified input. This is a bad idea - consider a username like `' or 1=1 --` - it's valid, in theory, but if your login system uses a line like `select * from users where username=$username and password=hash($password)`, you've just made an SQL injection point. This is more common than would be hoped.

Alternatively you can sanitise consistently across your application. If you pick this, you need to ensure that every possible way to log in (website, mobile application, API) uses the same sanitise process. You could (and this is a *bad* example - do not use in production) URL encode all characters in the username, so the same username would be stored as `%27+or+1%3D1+--`. This is slightly better than above, but might lead to unexpected issues if there are any problems with your sanitisation process. Can even hash them if you like, but then it gets very difficult to link reports from users with their records.

You also tend to print usernames within the application at various points. If you allowed any characters, you'd open your application to XSS vulnerabilities. This isn't avoided unless you output encode properly, but then you have the issue that what shows in the application might not actually work for logging in.

In terms of an email address as a username, in theory it's fine. But email addresses are perfectly capable of including pretty much all of the above issues too!

Comment: SQL Injection and XSS are a given but I'm interested in "stealing identity" too. For example, one benefit of requiring email verification on account creation is that someone cannot register your email address. Without verification of some sort, someone could create an account with your email and then when you decide to create an account you will receive an error message stating "this email is already taken".

Comment: Well, no, not unless the application knows that the username is also the email address. I could own `matthew@example.com`, and use the username `matthew`. You could have the username `matthew@example.com` and the email address `user@example.com` - no problem. Different fields. If you specifically use email addresses as usernames, that's different, but that has nothing to do with what characters are in the username.

Comment: We're definitely missing a Bobby Tables XKCD here...

Comment: Your answer seems to rely on the fact that Twitter doesn't correctly handle SQLi or XSS. I strongly suspect that is a false statement as they handle random input in so many places besides username.

Comment: @NeilSmithline It doesn't reference Twitter at all. It answers the question on bold, in a generic case.